# concurrency using ExecutorService

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, threadpoolexecutor

I have this simple program to count numbers from 1 to 9 using ThreadPool and ExecutorService.
Each Thread is waiting for 1 sec to execute. However, below program gives me random output for each execution.

How do I fix this so that it always produces 45?

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
    AtomicLong count = new AtomicLong(0);
    ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(10);
    List<Integer> list = Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9);
    for(Integer i : list) {
        executor.execute(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(1000);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                count.set(count.get() + i);
            }
        });
    }

    System.out.println("Waiting...");

    executor.shutdown();
    executor.awaitTermination(Long.MAX_VALUE, TimeUnit.MINUTES);
    System.out.println("Total::"+count.get());

    System.out.println("Done");
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a race condition?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34510/what-is-a-race-condition)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of

```
count.set(count.get() + i);
```

use

```
count.addAndGet(i);
```

Method *addAndGet* adds value atomically but sequential *get* and *set* is not atomic operation.

Answer (score 1):

AtomicLong has special methods which are atomic.  You only get atomic guarantees when using them (separate calls to `add()` and `get()` will *not* be atomic).  There are methods on AtomicLong which will "add" to the current value in an atomic fashion.